# sprintf with struct array field - gets segmentation fault

Tags: c

This idea is to format text info messages bellowing to a structure within a module.
It works like a charm when trying to define the message with (cf module.c):

```
/*this works*/
module_text3.info_text[0] = "toto[0]";
module_text3.info_text[1] = "toto[1]";
```

But when using sprintf, I got segmentation fault (cf module.c):

```
/*this gives segmentation fault*/
for(cpt=0; cpt < 2; cpt++)
{
  sprintf(module_text3.info_text[cpt], "info[%u]", cpt);
}
```

3 different files: main.c, module.h and module.c

```
/*main.c*/
/*gcc -o test main.c module.c*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include "module.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int i;
  struct message3 *ptext3 = moduleFcn3();

  for (i= 0; i < ptext3->info_nb; i++)
  {
    printf("ptext3->info_text[%u]: %s\n", i, ptext3->info_text[i]);
  }
  printf("ptext3->error_text: %s\n", ptext3->error_text);
  printf("ptext3->id: %u\n", ptext3->id);
  printf("ptext3->info_nb: %u\n", ptext3->info_nb);
  printf("ptext3->info_nb_max: %u\n", ptext3->info_nb_max);

  return 0;
}
/*------------------------------------------------------*/
/*module.h*/

#define NB_LINE_MAX 10
struct message3
{
  char *info_text[NB_LINE_MAX]; /*a few info lines.*/
  char *error_text; /*only one line for error.*/
  int id;
  int info_nb_max;
  int info_nb;
};

extern struct message3* moduleFcn3(void);

/*------------------------------------------------------*/
/*module.c*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include "module.h"

/*static is in "Stack".*/
static struct message3 module_text3;

struct message3* moduleFcn3(void)
{
  int cpt = 0;
  struct message3 *ptext;

  /*this gives segmentation fault*/
  for(cpt=0; cpt < 2; cpt++)
  {
    sprintf(module_text3.info_text[cpt], "info[%u]", cpt);
  }

  /*this works*/
//  module_text3.info_text[0] = "toto[0]";
//  module_text3.info_text[1] = "toto[1]";
//  cpt = 2;

  module_text3.error_text = "This is error";
  module_text3.id = 4;
  module_text3.info_nb_max = NB_LINE_MAX;
  module_text3.info_nb = cpt;

  ptext = &module_text3;

  return ptext;
}
```

I would appreciate any advises on how to format my information messages (with our without using sprintf).
Thank you,

Comment: The pointers in `char *info_text[];` and `char *error_text;`don't point to anything, so sprintf will write to random locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not allocated space for the strings in the `info_text` field. The simplest thing to do would be to change the `struct`:

```
/*module.h*/

#define NB_LINE_MAX 10
#define INFO_MAX 25

struct message3
{
  char info_text[NB_LINE_MAX][INFO_MAX]; /*a few info lines.*/
  char *error_text; /*only one line for error.*/
  int id;
  int info_nb_max;
  int info_nb;
};

extern struct message3* moduleFcn3(void);
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not allocate any memory for the info_text strings. You either have to use `malloc()` first, or if your C library supports it (the GNU one does), use `asprintf()` instead of `sprintf()` to have it allocate enough memory to hold the whole output string for you:

```
for(cpt = 0; cpt < 2; cpt++)
  asprintf(&module_text3.info[cpt], "info[%u]", cpt);
```

Don't forget that you also have to free the memory again at some point.

The reason that the following line works:

```
module_text3.info_text[0] = "toto[0]";
```

Is that the compiler ensures the string `"toto[0]"` is stored in memory somewhere, and you just make the pointer `module_text3.info_text[0]` point to that string.

Comment: Thank you guys. Solved. :-)